# How is remember token generated?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have `remeber_token` field in the users table. And i'm pretty much confused on how it is generated? because i can see two different types of tokens in the database for two different users.

`mFqEE5PUS4ZlOdQ51WEomGqJ1vFQCzw6zumvvW8rkpBUclC161HtvK8LsXXP`

and the other of kind:

```
78x6c35esh2Ya0g4fb1d9
```

How is it so? And are remember token and forgot password token generated with different algorithms?

Comment: Do you mean two users have different length of remember tokens or that the remember tokene has a different length than the reset token?

Comment: @sven aren't remember token and reset token updated on same `remember_token` field?

Comment: If i remember correctly you have a table named password_resets https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-passwords

Answer (score 0):

I looked [into the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php) and it has the following function to generate the token

```
protected function refreshRememberToken(AuthenticatableContract $user)
{
    $user->setRememberToken($token = Str::random(60));
    $this->provider->updateRememberToken($user, $token);
}
```

from [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-random):

> **str_random()**
>
> The str_random function generates a random string of the specified length. This function uses PHP's random_bytes function:

your token

> mFqEE5PUS4ZlOdQ51WEomGqJ1vFQCzw6zumvvW8rkpBUclC161HtvK8LsXXP

has 60 letters, i dont know why the other token has less.

Comment: is it the same for reset password?